# Bootloop and random restart issues in android (Gionee A1 plus)

Tags: charging, fastboot, boot-loop, 7.0-nougat, stock-android

My **Gionee A1 plus** started acting strange a month ago. It would often restart whenever I received any *SMS notification* and then boot up just fine. I tried using an earphone and keeping the phone in silent mode, as reducing the notification sound levels didn't help. This fixed the problem for a few weeks until 2 days ago while using my camera, it suddenly decided to restart but got stuck in a **bootloop**(the boot logo kept popping up and disappearing again and again). I managed to turn it off by plugging it to a charger where it went to *charging mode*.

After a bit of research, I entered the stock "**Android recovery mode**" and cleared the */cache partition* but that did not fix the issue. I panicked as I did not have a twrp or any other recovery tool installed. I didn't even have USB debugging enabled. However, after a bit more strolling I found that ***fastboot*** could detect my device(after *rebooting to bootloader*) and then ran the command `fastboot continue` and my phone booted up alright. But now my phone can't use the "Ultrafast charge mode" which makes the charging process 5 times longer and the battery drains really quick. What's more the phone restarting by itself has become often(I can't even use my camera) and its always the **bootloop**. I have to use ***fastboot*** to boot in again.

I created a backup of my data and then did a **factory reset** on the device to no use.

Do I need to flash a **stock ROM** to my device or am I missing something? I am inexperienced in this domain so please guide me on how to fix this issue. I have attached snaps of my *Recovery and Factory modes*.

[image: Recovery mode]

[image: Hardware details]

[image: fastboot commands]

**TLDR;** phone ends up in bootloop after suddenly restarting while in use, battery drains faster, no ultrafast charging, clearing cache and factory reset doesn't help.

Comment: even more worse your backup is useless because you didn't backup metadata partition from SP Flash Tool. unfortunately this is a bug in android system recovery

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did run the *root integrity check* and it passed with no errors. I hadn't tried rooting my device before either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually turned out to be a battery issue. After replacement, the phone works as good as new(or so it seems).

Answer (score 1):

Did it suddenly started to do weird things? Can you specify the cause.
As per the mentioned details, you need to flash stock firmware from SPFlash Tool(as you have a MTK device). You can google for your firmware. And flash it while your phone is in download mode.
I too have faced many bootlops while flashing roms. So I flash stock firmware and all good.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it started when I first started using meeting applications. Sometimes I would get an echo of background noise on the loudspeaker and the phone would reboot. Now the phone just can't store any charge or so it seems. Is it possible that it is a hardware problem of some kind?

Comment: After flashing the stock ROM (**SWW1617GI_0301_T5242** since I coudn't get the **T6953** one) the system booted fine. But after I removed the USB cable the phone died. It wouldn't reboot anymore even if I flash it again. It doesn't even get to the recovery menu without being powered and `fastboot continue` doesn't help anymore. I'm beginning to doubt it's a hardware issue(probably the battery) somehow.